# How to prevent double delete without smart pointers?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I just want to make sure not to mess up stuff. Suppose I have this struct:

```
struct Foo{
    struct Bar { virtual int calc(int x) = 0; };
    Bar* barX;
    Bar* barY;
    int x,y;
    Foo(Bar* bx,Bar* by) : barX(by),barY(by) {}
    void process(int xx,int yy){
        x = barX->calc(xx);
        y = barY->calc(yy);
    }
    ~Foo();
};

struct IDBar : Foo::Bar { int calc(int x) { return x; } };

int main() {
    IDBar* b = new IDBar();
    Foo f = Foo(b,b);
    Foo f2 = Foo(new IDBar(),new IDBar());
}
```

I cannot use C++11 (ie no smartpointers), and I am not 100% sure... **Is this the correct way to delete both (or possibly only one) of the `Bar` objects:**

```
Foo::~Foo(){
    if (barX == barY){ delete barX; }
    else { delete barX; delete barY; }
}
```

**?**

PS: The idea is that `Foo` owns the `Bar` objects (thus would be responsible for deleting them). The `Bar`s passed to the constructor are not supposed to be used for anything else. Actually a `Bar` can only belong to a single `Foo` (a flaw I realized only later, but that is fine for now). Moreover, `Foo` is not supposed to be copied (maybe I should prevent that explicitly).

Comment: Who owns the Bars?

Comment: What about boost smart pointers?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Foo owns the bars.

Comment: @KIIV sorry, no boost if possible

Comment: @tobi303: so, two Foos cannot have the same Bar?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yep, thats a flaw in my design, but I will accept it for now

Comment: Anyway, RAII is fundamental paradigm in c++, so you can use Rule of Tree do create class without double deletes.

Comment: @KIIV not sure how I would make use of RAII in this case, because I want to use polymorphic pointers

Comment: `Foo` is using RAII if it's taking ownership of resources and releasing them and as such @KIIV is making sure that you're aware of The Rule of Three ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Comment: @JamesAdkison ah ok, now I got the point. Actually `Foo` is not meant to be copyable, I guess I would have to delete corresponding default methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a slight disagreement with Taztingo. It's not unreasonable for an object to take ownership of a resource passed into it. This occurs in all sorts of real world code. The fact that the class takes ownership of resources passed into the constructor is documented and that's that. If someone improperly uses the class without consulting the documentation, they're shooting themselves in the foot.

It is true, however, that this is error prone, and we would like to catch these sorts of errors or prevent them from happening. If there was some way to guarantee that nobody else thinks they own the resource when `Foo` does, we'd be on our way. In C++11, this is easy with `std::unique_ptr`. In earlier C++ standards, there is `std::auto_ptr`. While earlier standards of C++ don't have move constructors, `std::auto_ptr` functions similarly by relinquishing the resource from an old `std::auto_ptr` upon assignment or copying to a new `std::auto_ptr`.

I recommend you use `std::auto_ptr`.

If the situation where the same resource is explicitly allowed to be passed in for both constructor parameters for the class `Foo`, create a new constructor that accepts only one `std::auto_ptr<Bar>`.

Finally, if you want to make it so that `Foo` cannot be copied, simply declare the copy constructor and assignment operator both as private.

Comment: @tobi303: I see, You have changed Your favorite answer. But it does not help, if You like to offer a use case, where a user can work with two objects Foo(a, b) and Foo(b, c) simultaneously!

Comment: @Roland I see what you mean. However, that use case cannot be supported anyway because I think the asker's intention is that `Foo` takes exclusive ownership of the pointer passed in. Passing `b` to two `Foo`s means it has two owners.

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue the comparisons are far from perfect - just imagine you had *three* pointers.

To ensure double `delete` never occurs, how about you call `delete` only one? Consider the scenario:

1. Allocate a pool of memory (let's say enought to allocate a thousand objects). This should be allocated on the heap via a regular `new` call, somewhere inside a new `PoolAllocator<T>` class, and `delete` within its desctructor.
2. Implement the pool so it supports the function `void* getMemory<T>()` returning memory for `T` to use, and advancing internal pointer.
3. Make sure whatever the `T` is called can only be created via placement new on the pool provided memory.

In the end, you need not worry about the memory - the pool object can be a regular stack variable, with internals on the heap.

Otherwise, what forbids you implementing your own proto-smart pointers?

Comment: but i have the same pointer in 2 different arrays

Answer (score 1):

no no no no. god no

```
Foo::~Foo(){
        if (barX == barY){ delete barX; }
        else { delete barX; delete barY; }
    }
```

It is very dangerous to delete memory that the object did not allocate by its self. Whatever owns those objects should delete them. In your case main should be in charge of deleting those allocated objects.

```
int main() {
    IDBar* b = new IDBar();
    IDBar* b2 = new IDBar();
    IDBar* b3 = new IDBar();
    Foo f = Foo(b,b);
    Foo f2 = Foo(b2,b3);
    delete b;
    delete b2;
    delete b3;
}
```

A perfect example of an object handling memory management in itself is a LinkedList. A LinkedList creates nodes inside its self. The user has no knowledge of them, and instead just inserts T. The LinkedList will then delete them when it is deleted. The user is only in charge of deleting the LinkedList because he or she created that.

```
std::list<MyObject*> list;
MyObject* object = new MyObject;
list.push_back(object);
//The list isn't going to delete object because it doesn't own it
delete object;
```

Comment: in general I am a bit allergic to writing in all caps and even apart from that, I dont really agree with your "NO NO NO...". The ownership is taken by `Foo` once i pass the `Bar` to the constructor, thus `Foo` should delete them and not anybody else.

Comment: Then why doesn't Foo own it?

Comment: because the user has to choose which kind of `Bar` to instantiate

Comment: Then Foo does not own it because it is dependency injection.

Comment: What do you have to say about `std::unique_ptr<MyWidget> widget(new MyWidget());`? Smart pointers certainly take ownership of pointers they didn't allocate.

Comment: I am not so familiar with dependency injection, but with the opposite logic I could say that it is not dependency injection, because `Foo` owns it

Comment: Sorry by own I mean allocate it. Foo does not allocate it, it should not delete it.

Comment: I never heard about this rule. What I know is: Who owns it has to delete it. And I know several examples of allocation and deletion done in two different places.

Comment: That's my point, you're saying `std::unique_ptr` didn't allocate it so it shouldn't delete it?

Comment: @JamesAdkison That is a good counter point. I do not have an answer for that specific. Maybe someone else can. I do know for a fact what he is doing with dependency injection can lead to unmaintainable code. He is planning for the developer to pass in an object. If that object is used in other places it will constantly need to be checked if its null, everywhere.

Comment: @JamesAdkison I can ask the reverse question and ask why LinkedList does not free the object that is passed in then? You can do the same thing with `list.push_back(new Object()).

Comment: afaik know containers are not meant to own their elements. I realized that I wasnt too clear about certain things and I will update the question

Comment: Because `std::unique_ptr` exists to **take ownership** and standard containers don't take ownership (i.e., `std::list<Object*>`) but can be told to (i.e., `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`). I'm just pointing out that the the owner of a resource should release it but the owner isn't necessarily the one to create the resource, as highlighted by `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist in your construction, and cannot heed the design rule of Taztingo; then the answer is yes: it is the correct way!

And then make a strong API documentation of the class Foo and it’s constructor, that the lifetime responsibility of the objects Bar is taken over.

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: I could heed that "rule", but I just dont understand it.

Comment: @tobi303: Tazingo makes a counter-example, that you cannot instantiate two objects Foo(a, b) and Foo(b, c) concurrently, therefore a strong API description is needed.